# Farseer getting lot of warnings

Tags: c#, xna, farseer

I am trying to run one of the farseer physics samples from http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/downloads/get/722127.
I am still getting these warnings and I don't know why. Any solutions?
Errors:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTvgX.png

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it these warnings are coming from the Farseer project, which means it was probably coded with these warnings.  These warnings suggest that there may be logical errors in the code, but they could also be completely harmless.

The only solution is to go through the warnings one-by-one, and correct them.  Of course, if you do that, you should probably work with whoever is maintaining the project to get your changes into the main branch.